# Reading the file one row in advance

Tags: c#

I have a rather big file, about 80MB, and want to break it into chunks.
My pipe delimited file structure is something like this:

```
Name|ID|Phone|Address
Al|34|3453453234|123 Main
Bo|456|44545|123 Main
Al|34|455666|5th Ave
James|007|7021023456|Green Ave
```

but as you see info of a person might be scattered through out the file so first with LINQ  wrote a file sorter to sort the rows of the file by ID so my file now looks like this:

```
Name|ID|Phone|Address
James|007|7021023456|Green Ave
Al|34|3453453234|123 Main
Al|34|455666|5th Ave
Bo|456|44545|123 Main
```

I want to say ok let's break this into smaller files and let's each file contain a maximum of 50 people. So the key thing and the also the main thing that I can't figure out is how to write the code in a way that ok each file contains max of 50 people in it **AND** make sure the records of each person are all in **THE SAME** file?

Comment: Does the file have to contain all records of one person even if the number is greater than 50?

Comment: @TimSchmelter YES. The most important point is ALL records of the person must be in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is something simpler but this should work:

```
var dataLines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\SplitFileTest\BigFile.txt")
    .SkipWhile(l => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).Skip(1); //skip header
var dataIdGroups = dataLines
    .Select(l => new { Line = l.Trim(), Fields = l.Trim().Split('|') })
    .Where(x => x.Fields.Length == 4)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = x.Fields[0],
        ID = x.Fields[1],
        Phone = x.Fields[2],
        Address = x.Fields[3],
        Line = x.Line
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID);

var allFileLines = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var userGroup in dataIdGroups)
{
    if (userGroup.Count() > 50 || allFileLines.Count == 0 || allFileLines.Last().Count + userGroup.Count() > 50)
        allFileLines.Add(userGroup.Select(x => x.Line).ToList());
    else
        allFileLines.Last().AddRange(userGroup.Select(x => x.Line));
}


for(int i = 0; i < allFileLines.Count; i++)
    File.WriteAllLines(
        string.Format(@"C:\Temp\SplitFileTest\UserFile_{0}.txt", i + 1), 
        allFileLines[i]);
```

I've tested it with some sample data and it created 4 files from one big, every user is always completely in one file. Only if the file contains less than 50 lines and the next user does fit into this file it is mixed.

Comment: Thanks Tim, This is the second time you have answered my questions on the site and helped me with this project :)

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper: i'm glad to help, note that currently the header is not added to the "child"-files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
// Take 50 records
var first50 = source.Take(50).ToList();

// Add all records which have the same name as the last taken record
var additional = source.TakeWhile(p => p.Name == first50.Last().Name);
```

Needs some corner case handling (empty file etc.), but the idea should work.

Comment: sounds like a good idea.  What is "source"? How is it defined?

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper That's wherever you are taking the data lines from. You surely are able to turn the input data into an IEnumerable collection, right?